# What is the better way to get the biggest value of a csv file with hadoop?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a huge csv file with 4 informations like that:

```
DF Alice 20.4
MG Bob 30.4
MG Clara 14.3
SP Daniel 40.2
...
```

I wrote a Hadoop map-reduce code to get the major value of all the table:

Mapper:

```
public class BolsaFamiliaMapper extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,
        DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { String
        valueString = value.toString();
        String[] SingleData = valueString.split("\t");
        output.collect(new Text("Biggest"), new
            DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(SingleData[2])));
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
public class BolsaFamiliaReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,
       DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text t_key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text,DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {
        Text key = t_key;
        double frequency = 0.0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            // replace type of value with the actual type of our value
            DoubleWritable value = (DoubleWritable) values.next();
            if (value.get() > frequency) {
                frequency = value.get();
            }
        }
        output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(frequency));
    }
}
```

If I understood well, the reduce execution will not run in parallel because the key that I used ("Biggest").

Is there a better way to get these major value?

Another doubts that I have is how can I get the tuple of the biggest value to check the UF (SP). Is it possible in the same map-reduce? If is possible, so can I classify the biggest values by UF?

I am beginner in map-reduce operations and hadoop, and I couldn't find any answer in other forums.

Comment: Do you have to use Java MapReduce? Why not Pig?

Comment: Yes I have. I am studying map-reduce and latter I will test on Pig too. But now I need to use Java MapReduce.

Comment: I think you've asked two question here... To find the overall greatest value, I believe you need a single reducer, yes, as that will force `Iterator<DoubleWritable> values` to have all the values you want to compare. As for "grouping by" this "UF" value. You replace `"Biggest"` for `SingleData[0]`

Comment: Thanks, it worked as well. You was very clear about the use of `values`. Actually I asked more than two questions, and now I only need to know how can I retrieve the tuple of the `biggest` value. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I believe `MapReduceBase` is a deprecated class, so you are learning outdated methods...

Regarding the title of the post

> What is the better way to get the biggest value of a csv file with hadoop?

The "better" way is don't use Java MapReduce. The other tools (Pig, Hive, Spark, etc.) are generally far better, especially for this simple task.

Now, as for finding the max from all the values - yes, you'll need a single key from the map, which is forced into a single reducer, and all associate values are then scanned for the max. Your code seems to be doing that.

Regarding the second question - you want to group on the first column. Simply use that column.

```
output.collect(new Text(SingleData[0]), new
        DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(SingleData[2])));
```

Now, that should theoretically run quicker than the `"Biggest"` key because you'll have many reducers for each output key.

---

As far as seeing what the value is, well, MapReduce usually will spit out a file into HDFS wherever your configured the job output to go. The `output.collect` method of the Reducer class is responsible for that.

Comment: Makes sense to group by UF and get only the biggest value, the problem happens because I have many UFs in the database. At the end, I was using two MapReuce class to solve the problem. About the tuple, I think that the question it wasn't clear: I'm trying to get the biggest value and save all the line of the csv file (`SP Daniel 40.2`) and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: About the deprecated class, I didn't know about that but for the purpose (learn the MapReduce paradigm) it was good.

Comment: Personally, I learned from the Hadoop Definitive Guide, which even that needs a new version... But, the documentation online is current. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Comment: I read a part and seems like a good guide. Thanks again. For the last, is there a way to get the all tuble of the biggest value? `(SP Daniel 40.2)`

Comment: Your output file should contain them all. You won't be able to get all the tuples directly from the code

Comment: My output (`part-00000`) has only the keys and its values (biggest).

Comment: What were you expecting? `Daniel` in the output? You need a custom Writable class, but  I'd recommend you create a new post for that if you don't understand what to do

Comment: I wrote a custom Writable class, i would like to know if it's possible to get the value without extra effort. But thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)